# Why do we need to convert total into string in the following code given below?

Tags: python, string

```
sum = 5 + 10
print sum

second_sum = 7 + 11
print second_sum

total = sum + second_sum
total_str = str(total)  

print "The total is", total
```

Comment: No idea. You haven't told us what language this is, therefore we can't say anything.

Comment: That's Python I asume. but the string variable `total_str` is not being used. And in Python you can simply concat a string and a numeric type.

Comment: Yes, its python. I got it here: https://bitbucket.org/mshibly/python-examples-from-intro-to-python-course/src/bc6a36de95156e397504206082e87755e950ee73/addtwonumbers.py?at=master

Comment: You don't. It's an unnecessary line. You would need to if you were doing this: `print "The total is " + total_str`

Comment: When I used print "The total is " + total_str It said Error: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' I think its not useful here.

Answer (score 3):

You don't. In fact, you are not even using `total_str` in that code. You are printing the value of `total`, not `total_str`. The `total_str = str(total)` line could be removed with no impact on the function of the program. The `print` command will convert any arguments to strings using `str` automatically.

Comment: Yup exactly. Thanks. Why was there in the first place creating confusion. :\

Comment: That's the danger in using code without understanding it. You were right to question this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you should use.

```
sum = 5 + 10
print sum

second_sum = 7 + 11
print second_sum

total = sum + second_sum
total_str = str(total)  

print "The total is", total_str
```

Comment: Why? His code works just fine. Why convert to a string when print will do it automatically?

Comment: Well it does not matter really then hey. It just because he went hrough the trouble of creating `total_str`, might as-well use it.

Comment: No, might as well delete it because it is not used ;-)

Comment: Just calling Blue, Blue. same all round, Deleting it is just cleaner I will give you that.

Comment: Anyhow, I did up-vote your answer.

Comment: There is no difference.